# Add two different GPUImage Filter on a GPUImage

Tags: android

I want to add two different GPUImage filters on an image. For a single filter I have use following code
 filter_bitmap= mGPUImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied(bitmap);
but I don't know how to apply two different filters on an image in android?

Answer (score 0):

using this,
example i apply two filter GPUImageGrayscaleFilter() and GPUImageColorInvertFilter()

code:

```
// add filter 1

 Bitmap filter_bitmap=mGPUImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied(bitmap);

 mGPUImage.setImage(filter_bitmap); 

 mGPUImage.setFilter(new GPUImageGrayscaleFilter());

 // add filter 2 

 Bitmap bitmap2 = mGPUImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

 mGPUImage.setImage(bitmap2); 

 mGPUImage.setFilter(new GPUImageColorInvertFilter());
```

Ok, maybe help you!